# Import CSV from UI in PowerApp

Tags: powerapps

I have a PowerApp connected to Common Data Services (CDS) very simple, just list products, add, remove or edit these products. But I have a more complex use case to solve: My user needs a button to import a CSV from App and this data should be loaded automatically in Common Data Services (CDS).

So, I tried some things but without success:

1) Create an attachment in a form, but I don't know how to make some process to read this attachment and load in CDS. 
2) Put the **Import Data** button (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/data-platform-import-export) in my UI, but this button just load "zip" exported from another PowerApp and this is not my case.

So, If not possible put a button to import CSV directly I can suggest to user import in another place but I don't know where, and should be very easy because my user don't have any IT Knowledges.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple approaches you could try, but it will be an epic hack to get it to work! I was able to customize [this Flow here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/import-csv/td-p/440472), to get you ~80% of the way there (its getting late). See [my version and a sample app here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/import-csv/m-p/458786/highlight/true#M52).

1. **Import the Flow into your environment**

   1. Add the `Create a record` Common Data Service action to the last step
2. **Edit your PowerApp:**

   1. Add an `Edit Form` control to your PowerApp
   2. Click `Data Source` and select your CDS table
   3. Click 'Fields' and add ONLY the `Attachments` field
   4. Set the Form `Default Mode` to `Edit`
   5. Insert an `Image` control. Set its `Image` property to `First(yourAttachmentControlName.Attachments.Value).Value`
   6. Insert a button control and select it
   7. Click `Action` then `Power Automate` and select the Flow you imported earlier.
   8. Epic hack time! Set the `OnSelect` property to:

```
Set(varCSV, imgDummyPic.Image); //whatever the name of your Image control is
Set(varCSV, JSON(imgDummyPic.Image,IncludeBinaryData));
CSV_TO_JSON_TO_CDS.Run(varCSV) //whatever the name of your Flow is
```

You can see all of this in action in the sample app. Connect the two, click the button, and dissect the results.